# Php doesn't seem to recognize the $this variable

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, this, private

I wrote some code and it has some weird behavior. **It throws fatal errors for all the private and protected variables I have declared, even if I use them with `$this` in front of them**. It seems like the scope of the `$this` variable is not recognized.

I use php version 7.1.0 and apache version 2.4.23 (and I installed the mpm worker),  Netbeans, Ubuntu 16.04. I also use pThreads (https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads). I searched on the internet and didn't found anything similar to this problems.

The Pool class from which my class extends is a class of pThreads.
e.g.

```
class interfacePool extends Pool {

public $data = array();
private $workerCount;
private $timeoutStart; 
private $timeout = 50; 

public function process() {

    $this->timeoutStart = microtime(true);

    $this->workerCount = count($this->workers);

    while ($this->workerCount > 0 && $this->timeoutStart + (float)$this->timeout > microtime(true)) {

        $this->collect(function ($task) {

            if ($task->isCompleted()) {

                $this->data = array_merge($this->data, json_decode($task->data, true));
                $this->workerCount--;

            }
            return $task->isCompleted();

        });

    }

    $this->shutdown(); 

    return $this->data;

}

}
```

And the error I'm getting is the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot access private property interfacePool::$timeoutStart in /usr//local/apache2/htdocs/01_Web/controllers/interface.controller.php:21

Stack trace:

```
0 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/01_Web/controllers/interface.controller.php(110): interfacePool->process()

1 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/01_Web/libs/core.class.php(221): interfaceCtrl->getTariffs()

2 /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/01_Web/index.php(35): core->run()

3 {main}
  thrown in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/01_Web/controllers/interface.controller.php on line 21
```

The line on which the error occurs is the `$this->timeoutStart = microtime(true)`.

The class `interfacePool` is in the `interface.controller.php` file (I'm not trying to access those variables from somewhere else). 
These errors occur through the whole project; everywhere I have protected or private variables.

Comment: Please post your "Pool" class too. Edit: Nevermind, it's from pthreads extension.

Comment: Please provide code of all files from your trace. The only thing i can imagine is that you have some dynamic call with a callable or something else. Therefore you are out of scope.

Comment: the pool class is from pthreads, you can see it here: https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/blob/master/classes/pool.h

Comment: pthreads already has a version for PHP 7.1? Afaik it is not that updated yet.

Comment: The problem is not with the code, because the same one works on other computers which were already setup. The problem is with some of the configurations.

Comment: @PEMapModder Only the PECL/last tagged version isn't, master should work with it though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It simply is a bug in pthreads.

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/commit/c521adc7b645b9a60f8c3e9b6f1331c7dc6b428b is using `EG(fake_scope)` wrongly, ending up with a `NULL` scope for the constructor call instead of `zend_get_executed_scope`. (This line `fcc.calling_scope = scope;` should be `fcc.calling_scope = zend_get_executed_scope();` instead.)

And a `NULL` scope is, internally, equivalent to not being in any class context (i.e. no private nor protected access), explaining your behavior here.

**Update**: Fixed in https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads/commit/ec1b2fdd6e562db7224662ed79125d8f6dde9f44

Comment: I have pinged the maintainer of pthreads about it http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34653904#34653904 - hope it'll be fixed soon :-)